# Get the last line with consecutive pattern

Tags: tcl

I have a pattern in a line and I want to get the last line if there are consecutive occurrence in the file.

Example file:

```
apple 1
banana 5
banana 6
apple 2
apple 5
apple 7
banana 9
```

Expected output:

```
apple 1
banana 6
apple 7
banana 9
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that each line is a proper list, it's a matter of remembering the last line and printing the previous value when it is different to the current one.

```
gets $fin oldline;        # Assume there's at least one line for simplicity of coding
while {[gets $fin newline] >= 0} {
    if {[lindex $newline 0] ne [lindex $oldline 0]} {
        puts $oldline;    # There was a difference, so print out the old one
    }
    set oldline $newline; # Save the new line we read for the next iteration
}
puts $oldline;            # The last line to be read hasn't been printed yet
```

Determining whether two lines are the same is the main problem; it's likely to be more complex with real data than just applying `lindex`. This is where you get into using `regexp` or `scan` to parse the data, and how you do that is a non-trivial problem that requires actually understanding the format of the real data.

Dealing with the case of having no lines at all is a separate matter. Do that by checking for the return value of that initial `gets`, and if it is less than zero, not going into the loop or printing the final value at all.